# Is there any jQuery plug-in for a Stackoverflow-like "Please login or register" box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

The "Please login or register" box from Stackoverflow (that appears when you try to vote unlogged) is a good unobstrusive alert dialog.

I'm after a jQuery plug-in that, given a referential html element, it would show the box aligned to that element.

It would be awesome, any tips?

Any similar solution for an unobstrusive jQuery alert would also be acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

[qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) is a great jQuery plugin for positioned tooltips with lots of options through an easy-to-use API. [Here are some demos](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/)

This snippet would probably do it:

```
$('.your_a_elements').qtip(
  {
    content: "I'm being hovered",
    show: { when: { event: 'click' } }
  }
);
```

(The corny syntax for enabling on `click` gets totally excluded if you want it to appear on hover/mouseover)

Comment: qTip2 has been in the making for quite some time, when it eventually gets finished it should be even better. http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you can find something like this either with jQuery UI or jQModal or a combination of the two.